# How to execute multiple cmd commands using maven?

Tags: java, maven, build, pom.xml

I want to run multiple `CMD` commands in maven using single `pom.xml.`

May I know how can I do that?

for example

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>id1</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <executable>cmd1</executable>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>id2</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <executable>cmd2</executable>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions> </plugin>
```

Comment: So what's the problem? Does it work or does it not work? Apart from that why do you need to execute something os specific in a build? Some kind of a test ? If yes the `install` phase looks wrong.

Comment: no its just a example. i want to run grunt command when i build my project.

Comment: I'm not sure but than this might be the better solution: https://github.com/allegro/grunt-maven-plugin

Answer (score 0):

You could introduce two different [profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) for cmd1 and cmd2.

Comment: No its not like that its just a example. I want to run a grunt command  by using cmd

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [exec-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/index.html):

run a script that will run your cmds sequentially::

```
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.2</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>run a backup</id>
              <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <executable>/path/to/backup-script/bkp.sh</executable>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
```